# PDO statement property stored as object property and accessed by object methods

Tags: php, pdo

I know the title doesn't give much clues about what I'm asking for, so here's the simplified situation:

```
class MyPDO extends PDO
{
    private $stmt;

    function __construct($dsn...)
    {
        parent:__construct($dsn...);
    }

    function myQuery($sql)
    {
        $this->stmt = $this->query($query);
    }

    function myFetchAll()
    {
        return $this->stmt->fetchAll($mode);
    }

    function myFetchRow()
    {
        return $this->stmt->fetch();
    }
```

}

Throughout the application I have a base instance of MyPDO and pass it to different objects, mappers.

```
$adapter = new MyPDO($dsn...);
$adapter->myQuery('SELECT * FROM table');
$rows = $adapter->myFetchAll();

$another_object = new ObjectThatNeedsPDO($adapter);
$another_object->adapter->myQuery('SELECT * from another_table');
$rows = $another_object->adapter->myFetchAll();
```

Is this approach safe, especially from the MyPDO::stmt perspective? Can the application flow mess things up so I can end up fetching data from another $stmt than expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I would not take your approach.  The reason being that I would not want the possibility of a statement object created by one class being exposed to another unrelated class.  Additionally, each implementing class may have different sorts of parameter binding which it needs to perform, ways in which it needs to access the data (i.e. fetch all rows, fetch each row, fetch as objects vs. arrays, etc.), ways in which to handle errors in a class-specific way, and so forth.

To me you are gaining nothing by having this logic inside of some child of the base PDO class.  I mean is it really much harder to do:

```
$stmt = $this->pdo->query(...)
$data = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

than:

```
$this->myPDO->query(...);
$data = $this->myPDO->myFetchAll();
```

What do you gain other than a unnecessary coupling of this additional class to all the classes which will consume it?  Really, the statement interactions are always going to be very class specific with really the only common functionality (the DB connection) being provided by the base PDO instance.

As such, certainly feel free to pass around a common PDO instance amongst classes, this is definitely a good practice (i.e. dependency injection).

Just think really hard about whether you want to potentially change every single implementing class when you make changes to your proposed myPDO class, or whether you want to change your myPDO class every time some implementing class needs some custom means to interact with the statement object.

Based on discussions below, it seems you may want to consider extending PDOStatement to give you the maximum flexibility.

This might look like this:

```
class myPDOFactory {
    public static function getInstance($dsn, $pdo_statement_class = 'myPDOStatement', $pdo_constructor_args = NULL);
        $pdo = new PDO($dsn);
        if (empty($pdo_statement_class)) {
            $pdo_statement_class = 'PDOStatement';
        }
        if (empty($pdo_constructor_args) || !is_array($pdo_constructor_args)) {
            $pdo_constructor_args = array();
        }
        $config_array = array($pdo_statement_class, $pdo_constructor_args);
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_STATEMENT_CLASS, $config_array);
        return $pdo;
    }
}

class myPDOStatement extends PDO Statement {
    public function __construct(<any custom parameters you may need to have passed - items in $pdo_constructor_args from myPDOFactory class>) {
        parent::__construct();
        // any special stuff you want to do with any passed parameters here
    }

    public function fetchAll() {
        // override any functionality you desire here
    }

    public function fetchAllObjects() {
        return $this->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    }
}

class someClassThatNeedsPDO {
    protected $pdo = NULL;
    public function __construct($pdo) {
        if($pdo instanceof PDO) {
            $this->pdo = $pdo;
        } else {
            throw new Exception('Ooops!');
        }
    }

    public function doSomethingWithPDO() {
        $stmt = $this->PDO->prepare('SELECT * FROM sometable');
        $stmt = execute();
        return $stmt->fetchAllObjects();
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
$pdo = myPDOFactory::getInstance($dsn, 'myPDOStatement', $constructor_args);
$consuming_class = new someClassThatNeedsPDO($pdo);
$object_array = $consuming_class->doSomethingWithPDO();
```

Comment: Mike, as I commented on Ray's answer, that was just a very **simplified** example. I assure you that MyPDO (even the name is for example and not the real one) has plenty of methods and exception handling that **really** extends the base PDO. Regarding the way other classes **will** interact with MyPDO, I'll make sure I'll have it all covered in MyPDO. Anyway, the thing I was interested in was if it's safe from the MyPDO::stmt point of view, and your answer was affirmative, right?

Comment: And yes, you are right, that would make $stmt available from one class to another and that's just wrong. I'll have $stmt returned by the query to a different variable outside MyPDO and passed to fetch functions when needed. Thanks for pointing that out for me!

Comment: @Stingus Thanks for clarifying.  In your case, it might perhaps make better sense to extend on the functionality of PDOStatement rather than PDO. You can then set your PDO attribute (via `PDO::setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_STATEMENT_CLASS, $config_array)`) to have PDO issue statement objects of your specified class type.  Or you might use a mix of your own PDO extension (which has this appropriate attribute set on the connection) and PDOStatement extension.  I would recommend extending functionality along the same lines as the way functionality is currently broken up between PDO and PDOStatement.

Comment: @Stingus See updated answer for code examples related to my last comment.

Answer (score 1):

You're approach looks like a needless layer of obstraction, but this should work fine.  I'd add a check in your `fetch` methods to ensure a valid PDOstatement exists before calling the native fetch/fetchall.

Also, I'd recommend not creating a new connection for every MyPDO object.  Pass in a PDO connection.

Comment: As I said, that was the **simplified** PDO extension. I know the example is needless and just duplicates methods of the base PDO but copy / pasting the whole class here was pointless. I was interested if the approach was ok, and your answer is yes.

Answer (score 0):

I always use a singleton pattern when dealing with PDO (and previously with a mysqli wrapper). This means you only ever have one instance and you don't have to pass it to other classes. The way you're doing it is okay and safe, but using a singleton is better.

Making a singleton is really easy:

```
class myClass{
    private static $instance;

    public static function singleton()
    {
        if (!self::$instance) {
            return self::$instance = new myClass();
        } else {
            return self::$instance;
        }       
    }

    public static function myQuery($query)
    {
        #Do stuff
    }
}
```

When you create the instance, just call:

```
myClass::singleton()
```

And then if you want to use the methods, just use this:

```
myClass::myQuery($query)
```

IF you're using namespaces, you'll need to use the fully qualified name, e.g. my\namespace\myClass

Hope that makes sense!

Comment: That makes sense, you **absolutely** make sure that you'll end up with only one instance of PDO, while my approach is less strict. Didn't quite get why you use `static` on myQuery, but that's just off-topic.

Comment: You have to make the myQuery static otherwise you can't use the double colon operator (used to call static functions).

Comment: But you can always call it like `$instance->myQuery()`